# Webview preload not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, webview, electron, node-webkit

I've created electon applicaton from index.html page ;)

In index.html page i created webview element, like this:

```
<webview id="trello" src="https://trello.com" disablewebsecurity preload="./webview.js"></webview>
```

But when i opened devtools i got this error:

```
Unable to load the preload script: D:\<%path_to_my_work_folder%>\webview.js
```

How to fix this? How to load javascript file?

P.S: Yes, i create webview.js in root of project folder ;)